# Cocoa error in Registration

Tags: ios

In my signup field i am facing a issue like

> Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start
>   with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.)
>   UserInfo=0x7fa9b4841a00 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start
>   with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

        NSDictionary *parameters=@{@"IsSignUp":@1,@"MemberId":@0,
                                   @"UniversalMemberId":@"",
                                   @"FirstName":@"Dinakaran",
                                   @"MiddleName":@"",
                                   @"LastName":@"M",
                                   @"Gender":@"",
                                   @"DOB":@"01/06/1981",
                                   @"MaritalStatus":@0,
                                   @"MobileNo":@"",
                                   @"MobileNoAlt":@"",
                                   @"PhoneNo":@"",
                                   @"PhoneNoAlt":@"",
                                   @"EmailId":@"",
                                   @"EmailIdAlt":@"",
                                   @"OccupationId":@0,
                                   @"ProfilePicture":@"null",
                                   @"RecordStatus":@"A",
                                   @"CreatedBy":@0,
                                   @"PlanID":@3,
                                   @"UserName":[self EncodeBase64:UserName.text],
                                   @"Pwd":[self EncodeBase64:password.text],
                                   @"IMEI":@123};


        NSString *user = [UserName text];
        NSString *pass  = [password text];
        NSLog(@"Data saved");


        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        [defaults setObject:user forKey:@"UserName"];
        [defaults setObject:pass forKey:@"password"];

        [defaults synchronize];

        AFJSONRequestSerializer *serializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

        [serializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [serializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [serializer setValue:@"basic Vnl0YWxpdHlNNA==" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
        manager.requestSerializer = serializer;
        NSString *web=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",regurl,@"Users"];
        [manager POST:web parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];

    }
```

Comment: show your NSJSONSerialization part

Comment: Scroll down please@Anbu.Karthik